# Accessing Headers in .NET Core and Autofac

Tags: autofac, .net-core

In Autofac for 4.6 I was able to grab the headers via `HttpRequestMessage` with `builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage`. In .NET Core I cannot find a similiar function. Is there a way to accomplish this in .NET Core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the answers here are correct, but let's help you out a little further. Your question essentially boils down to how can you access headers inside a .net core app.

### If you are inside a controller

There is a property available in all Controllers named "HttpContext" which you are able to access headers with.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var requestHeaders = HttpContext.Request.Headers;
    var responseHeaders = HttpContext.Response.Headers;
    return View();
}
```

### If you are inside a service

This is a bit more work but still relatively simple.

In your startup.cs, in your ConfigureServices method you need to add a singleton for IHttpContextAccessor. The method will end up looking pretty close to this :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Now, inside your service, you actually need to inject in the IHttpContextAccessor. Here's a sample service that shows you how you might do it.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public IHeaderDictionary GetRequestHeaders()
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
    }
}

public interface IMyService
{
    IHeaderDictionary GetRequestHeaders();
}
```

Then you need to add to your services collection your service etc, and then have that injected into your controller.

For a bit more info about accessing the HttpContext in .net core read here : http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/05/accessing-httpcontext-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thanks much! Perfect example

Comment: The `IMyService` seems to be overly generic. There should never be some business logic that is interested in all request headers. So instead, I would advise defining role-based interfaces, where the interface is specified for the application's particular needs. For instance, I imagine an `ITenantContext` interface with a `string CurrentTenant { get; }` property. The underlying `AspNetTenantContext` implementation will load the value from the request headers. Likewise there could be other interfaces as well, such as `IUserContext` etc., that are focussed on one particular question.

Answer (score 1):

[If you're writing middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware), your `Invoke` method gets an `HttpContext` passed in.

If you're in a controller, the `HttpContext` and `Request` [are both properties right on the controller that get populated for you](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1dd1d49321eab65431e9c4b0465d7d9f2b23dbdf/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L43).

If you're in some other service, you'll need an `IHttpContextAccessor` registered and you can then resolve that. [Here's an example from the MVC repo.](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/89bd6dc1cd188772f9b85eb75ec0d79506a3bf2f/test/WebSites/BasicWebSite/Startup.cs#L25)

None of that is Autofac-specific. That's just how it works in ASP.NET Core.